# Signal Generated from Transmitter

Tags: waves, signal-processing

Suppose that we have a transmitter of $150.100\ \mathrm{ MHz}$.

We also have a receiver at a fixed point.

The transmitter constantly generates signals toward the direction of the receiver.

---

Based only on those facts what we can say about the following:

$1)$ Do we know the value of the signal generated by the transmitter at a given time point, i.e. do we know the value $s(t)$??

$2)$ If the signal generated by the transmitter is $s(t)$, the received signal at the receiver will be the same or different from $s(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, transmitter does not emit in a specific direction - e.g., a radio station would emit signals in all directions (as a spherical or cylindrical wave), so that whoever has a receiver can receive them. Creating a directed signal is usually a lot more complicated.

If we are the ones transmitting the signal, then we typically know what we are transmtting, i.e., we know $s(t)$. This is not the case when receiving signal for several reasons, most notably:

- The signal is distorted via traveling through the atmosphere or a transmission line - usually due to some degree of dispersion inherent to all the transmission lines.
- Every receiver is characterized by a response function, which describes how it transforms signals of certain frequency.
- The signal is usually mixed with various noises and other signals, which the transmitter needs to separate.

Comment: So, in general, we know what signal $s(t)$ we transmit, and the receiver has a response function that tries to explain the distorted signal that it receives. Also, in addition to that what is the connection between $s(t)$ (if there is any) and the signal strength measures from a receiver ??